# Show answers in profile page by the active status of question rather than answer update timestamp

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Profile page 'answers' sections allows to sort my answers with below options

votes → highest voted answers to lowest voted answers

Activity → recent updated answers (sorted by my answer update timestamp)

newest  → Sorts based on the my answered time stamp(edit timestamp won't be considered)

[image: Profile screenshot]

Current feature allows to sort based on my answered timestamp(first post or last update), this won't help us to know whether any changes made to questions(answered by me).

Ex: Recently, I answered a question & OP said, he is 'OK' with the answer. I thought his problem is resolved.

Now, the OP has offered a bounty to the question. So, clearly OP is looking for better answers. His problem is not solved. I am not aware that the changes happening in this question as current 'sorting by activity' lists this question in the bottom of my answered list.

I suggest that, we should have a option to sort the answers based on the activity on the question(not by my answer's update timestamp).
Latest activity on the question can be defined as max timestamp of any one of the below

- OP updates the question
- anyone offers bounty on my answered question
- anyone puts a comment.

#### Pros:

Allows to followup my own answers (update/improve)

A similar feature at  questions section(in profile page), reminds the OP to followup or taking care of his own questions

Comment: Why remove the cons?

Comment: I have changed my opinion after seeing the performance of stackexchange home page

Comment: You could *abuse* the favorite tab for that. If you favorite the question you answered, you can see the most recent active questions.

Comment: @rene, that's a nice alternative for me. So, using this single page, I can decide (to open/not to open the question) without opening all the links. Thanks. +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'[rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276168/show-answers-in-profile-page-by-the-active-status-of-question-rather-than-answer#comment895583_276168)' suggestion works fine.

We don't even need to check the favorites tabs for updated info.

If there is any activity, favorite tab will put a number.

[image: Profile page favorites tab]

For example, in the above screenshot, favorite tab has '5'. Which means, there is a new activity in 5 questions Favorited by me.

It has an additional information such as the user who made activity in that question as well as time duration along with his reputation.

Answer (score 1):

This kinda contradicts the necessary for seeing the activity for ***answers*** rather than questions.

Simply put, keep the activity for answers away from questions. The constant updates will not only slow you down a lot and will ***seriously*** annoy a lot of people with a lot of answers like Shog9 or Jon Skeet for example. It is not SE's job to inform you about ***everything that happens if it involves you in someway or another***. If you want to find out, find out yourself.

> Allows to followup my own answers (update/improve)

If your answer in your opinion is the best you can do and the OP is not pleased, that is fine! Gain some upvotes there and there and if the OP is not quite satisfied, there will be two clear ways of knowing:

- Your answer is not accepted
- And possibly, the OP comments on your answer about the new problems he faces

So this feature will still be unneeded.

> A similar feature at questions section(in profile page), reminds the OP to followup or taking care of his own questions

The OP will be constantly checking his/her questions as they are pinged when:

- Someone edits their post (sometimes)
- Someone answers their question
- Someone comments on their question or using `@OP's_username`

This feature is still not necessary.

Comment: I don't think there will be performance issues with realtime updates in profile page. For ex: Stackexchange home page runs with realtime update ==> http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime

Comment: SE usually use cache though

Comment: [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277658/314988) works fine.